# Retrieve collection in domain class from Database

Tags: grails, grails-orm

We use dynamic scaffolding in our project and hence place maximum coding in Domain itself.

I have a requirement where I want to retrieve a collection for a Domain class property from the same domain class.
Example :

```
class Person{

String name

String school

}
```

school property should be a dropdown containing list of all schools so far available in the Person table. If no value available, it can be empty dropdown.

Any suggestions to achieve this in domain class itself?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19240830/how-to-save-object-in-grails/19241203#19241203 see here

Comment: The above thread is for use of static values. i want to retrieve values dynamically from DB. Thanks

Comment: why not to use Domains: Person and Schools ?

Answer (score 0):

That is what 
static hasMany is for: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/hasMany.html

in your case, something like below will work , once you create a School Domain object:

```
class Person{

...

static hasMany = [schools: School]
...
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand it can be achieved via another domain object. I do not have a separate table for 'School'. I cannot create one new table too as the database is existing one and cannot be modified. School is just one of the rows of Person table. So, just to avoid complex mappings, we just look for kind of shortcut in same Domain class.